# Usage of terms like ''tools'' and ''equipment'' for a piece of software?

Tags: word-usage, usage, terminology

Is it okay to use  terms like ''tools'' and ''equipment'' for a piece of computer software in technical(for example electrical engineering ) documentation ?

For example, is it okay to use terms like ''tools'' and ''equipment'' for softwares ''visual studio'' or ''matlab''?

Comment: "Tools" is probably fine.  But I don't think there is enough context to write an answer.  Could you give an example of what you actually want to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "tool" or "tools" in this context makes sense and is fairly common among software developers.

The use of "equipment" almost always refers to some hardware in this context.  A laptop, a desktop computer, a router, etc.

I have never heard the word "equipment" refer to software tools such as Visual Studio or Matlab.